# Why does this script get to linger after having seemingly exited from Ctrl-C?

Tags: shell, signals, timeout, process-groups

I have a script, `script-A`, which runs `script-B`. When run under the terminal, it terminates as expected from Ctrl-C, but when run via `ssh` it continues to silently run after Ctrl-C even though `ssh` disconnects as usual.

`~/bin/script-A.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script will create 15 empty files in your ~/log dir.
# If you run it via `ssh localhost ~/bin/script-A.sh`,
# it will keep doing so even after having seemingly exited!

for i in $(seq 1 15); do
  touch ~/log/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S')__still_here.log
  timeout --foreground 1000 ~/bin/script-B.sh
  # echo 'here' # if uncommented, this kills the script!!
done
```

`~/bin/script-B.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script allows `script-A.sh` to keep running after Ctrl-C!

function retry {
  ${@}
  echo "here" # this is needed to repro the behavior!!
}

retry timeout 1 sleep 1000
```

I can reproduce this behavior on both Linux and macOS, so it seems to be intended behavior. But what precise mechanism could be causing it?

Comment: You don't use `ssh -t` for this, right?

Comment: Interesting, `ssh -t` shows that it is still running after Ctrl-C.